# Symfony/Monolog: How to write logs in my own channel/file

Tags: symfony, logging, monolog

I have a service in my services.xml:

```
<parameter key="monolog.logger.class">Monolog\Logger</parameter>
<service id="mylogger" class="%monolog.logger.class%">
  <tag name="monolog.logger" channel="myImportChannel" />
  <argument>myImport</argument>
</service>

<service id="myservice">
  <argument type="service" id="mylogger" />
</service>
```

my config.yml

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        myImport:
            type:     stream
            path:     /vagrant/app/logs/myImport.log
            channels: [myImportChannel]
```

When I call my Service I log a sample text. But the file is not written.
But I get an output on my console

```
[2015-01-16 12:06:16] myImport.ERROR: THIS IS A TEST [] []
```

Do I forget to configure something?
THANKS FOR ANY HELP!!!